# Finding all solutions to Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

**Edit:** I've rewritten this whole question because it was unclear.  I'm not sure if this is any better.  This is a multi-step problem using MATLAB, so I've tried to whittle it down a bit without losing anything.

> Let $A$ be a random 6x6 matrix, and $b$ be a random 6x1 matrix.  Since $A$ was generated randomly, we would expect it to be nonsingular.  The system $Ax = b$ should have a unique solution.
>
> Now let's change $A$ so that it is singular.  Replace the third column of $A$ with a linear combination of its first two columns, namely $a_3 = 4*a_1 + 3*a_2$, where $a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$ are first, second and third columns of $A$.
>
> Now let $y$ be a random 6x1 matrix and let $c = Ay$.
>
> Compute the reduced row echelon form $U$ of $[A$ $c]$.
>
> The free variable determined by the echelon form should be $x_3$.  By examining the system corresponding to the matrix $U$, you should be able to determine the solution corresponding to $x_3 = 0$.  Let the column vector $w$ be this solution.
>
> Now set the last column of $U$ to zeros.  So $U$ should now correspond to the reduced row echelon form of $(A | 0)$.  Use $U$ to determine the solution to the homogeneous system when the free variable $x_3 = 1$ and enter your result as vector $z$.
>
> Set $v = w + 3 * z$.  The vector $v$ should be a solution to the system $Ax = c$.  Why?  Explain. . . . What is the value of the free variable $x_3$ for this solution?

Here is the part I'm stuck on:

> How could we determine all possible solutions to the system in terms of the vectors $w$ and $z$?  Explain.

Comment: Not sure whether the question is complete or well expressed, since whether all solutions to $Ax=b$ are found will depend on dimensional considerations. But as a hint, you can use linearity - and so if $Ay$ also $=b$ then ...

Comment: Do you know [rank+nullity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) and [nullspace basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(matrix)#Basis) concepts?

Comment: I've rewritten the question as it wasn't clear enough.  I hope it's better.  No, I'm just starting and haven't covered vector spaces yet.

Comment: Since $w$ is a solution to $Ay = c,$ and $z$ is a solution to $Ax = 0,$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray} Aw & = & c, \\ Az & = & 0 \end{eqnarray}$$
We can deduce that
$$\begin{eqnarray} A(3z) & = & 0, \\ A(w + 3z) & = & c + 0, \\ A v & = & c \end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference to "the free variable" is unclear. Generally, if $A$ is a singular matrix, the solution space can have any number of dimensions. Even if it has one dimension, there is generally not one specific free variable; in the general case any variable can be regarded as "free" and the others expressed in terms of it. Thus, "with the free variable set to zero" is not a well-defined description of $w$.

For general singular $A$, it's not possible to express all solutions of the system in terms of only two vectors. However, you seem to be implicitly assuming that the solution space is one-dimensional. In that case, all solutions are of the form $w+\lambda z$ with arbitrary $\lambda$.

By the way, the fact that $v=w+3z$ is also a solution to $Ax=b$ follows from the other facts given and isn't required for the solution.

Comment: But how do you know that all solutions are of the form $w + \lambda z$ with arbitrary $\lambda$?  That's what I want to know.  What is the procedure for figuring out where the lambda goes and so forth?

Comment: @Matt: See [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Relation_to_nonhomogeneous_systems).

Comment: Ok, thanks Joriki!

Comment: @Matt: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

To fill out my comment above - the construction tells us that we are looking for a 1-dimensional subspace.

If $Aw=c$ and $Ay=c$ then, by linearity $A(w-y)=0$

and since we have a solution: $Az=0$, and we are dealing with a 1-dimensional subspace, $(w-y)$ must be a multiple of that solution, i.e.

$w-y=\lambda z$

As joriki has stated.

Comment: I guess my confusion lies in the fact that I'm trying to prove it in a more elementary manner.  My book hasn't thus far mentioned the relationship between homogeneous and nonhomogeneous systems.  All it has said about an m x n homogeneous system is that if n > m then at least one nontrivial solution exists, and that if A is a nonsingular matrix, then Ax = 0 has only the trivial solution.  It hasn't discussed dimension or subspaces or anything.  I can see that if Az = 0, then Aw + tAz = c for any constant t, but what if it were more complicated?  What if we wanted some combination of 3 vectors

Comment: w, x, z such that rAw + sAx + tAz = c.  Then I would need some algorithm to figure out values r and s.  I'm assuming x is some solution independent of w and z.  I don't know, I guess I'm overthinking this.